# Yahoo groups is going away: how can I download the old messages?

Tags: web-access

It looks like all the old email messages from my group are stored in web pages with URLs that look like this:

```
page="https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/arco-75/conversation/messages/19291"
```

That's email number 19291, and the others have the same form but different numbers at the end. What I am hoping to do is to grab all the old messages. The problem is that:

```
ans = Import[page]
```

returns stuff that begins with "Sorry, an error occurred while loading the content." From the look of it, I'm guessing that the problem is that my Import statement is not "logged in" to or a member of the group, and so it is rejecting the request. Does anyone know how to navigate the yahoo site to enable downloading of the old messages?

Comment: There is no such page. The URL given 404 page not found.

Comment: To follow up on what @Nasser is saying, we might need to be logged in to even see if. I can see https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/arco-75/info but nothing beyond that.

Comment: I managed to login programmatically, thanks to Mathematica supporting cookies, in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200995/using-urlexecute-to-login-to-website/201000#201000). Maybe it can also be helpful for this question. But it is not unlikely that it won't help, because Yahoo might do tricky stuff to prevent people from logging in programmatically. In any case, you need to know how to inspect the HTML of the login form to figure out what POST request to send to login.